# AVPlayerViewController picture in picture black screen appear

Tags: swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working on a video player and want to add the Picture-in-Picture feature. I added this feature(using AVPictureInPictureController), and it works perfectly, except for one issue. After I clicked the PiP button, PiP activated, but this black screen with "The video is playing in the picture in picture" appeared. I need to remove this black screen. How to hide this screen after the PiP button is tapped? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORV9n.png)

```
    let Player = AVPlayerViewController()
    Player.delegate = self
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
    Player.player = avPlayer
    Player.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
    if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {
        Player.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    do {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(.playback)
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch(let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    present(Player, animated: true, completion: nil)
    Player.player?.play()
```